# Generated .apk includes unused resources and unused classes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am developing a very simple application for Android, which literally all it does is display the current time and date on the screen. With this in mind I was expecting the app to be only a couple of kilobytes in size, but this is not the case.

After generating a "release" of the application, and analyzing it with **Build > Analyze APK...** in Android Studio, I can see that an extensive amount of .png and .xml resource files are placed into the .apk file, and I never used nor included any of them (my project only contains 4 resource files). This bothers me because these auto-included resource files do nothing but occupy space.

These are the auto-included folders (in blue) which contain the files I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, that's about 26% of the app's size.

A similar case occurs with the "classes.dex" file which contains hundreds (possibly thousands) of classes that I never reference in my code. For instance, after looking at what the file contains I found "HashMap" in it, which makes no sense for it to be included since I never imported it in my code.

So finally, my question is: **Is it possible to somehow avoid these unused resource files and classes from being included in the release of the .apk?**

NOTE: I am already using

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

in my "build.gradle" file, which does indeed reduce the size of the .apk, however the unused elements I have described above are still included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I never used nor included any of them

If you have `dependencies`, those classes and resources came from them.

> Is it possible to somehow avoid these unused resource files and classes from being included in the release of the .apk?

Eliminate your dependencies.

For example, when you created the project, you may have been presented with a "Backwards Compatibility (AppCompat)" checkbox, pre-checked. Leaving that checked adds a dependency on `appcompat-v7` and sets up your project to use it (e.g., your activity extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`). There are pros and cons for using `appcompat-v7`; one of the cons is that it adds a fair bit of overhead to your project.

Comment: Awesome! This has solved both the unused resources and the non-referenced classes (there are still a few non-referenced classes that are included in the .apk, but not nearly as close as before). Just to clarify, I solved the problem by removing some non necessary "implementation" in the "dependencies" section of the "build.gradle" file. Thanks!

Comment: @Sorin: Note that the APK Analyzer shows both classes that are in your app and classes/methods of external things (e.g., the framework) that are referenced by classes in your app.