# How to remove unwanted support v4 drawable folders

Tags: android

[image]

I didnt using any of these v4 drawable files in my app, is there any way to remove those unwanted drawable folders? They aren't showing in the project folder. They are visible when using the apk analyzer

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources` to `true` to exclude the unused resources of your app in your apk.

Check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code?hl=en#shrink-resources

**EDIT**

I would say that those resources are from libraries you are including in your `build.gradle`.

The only thing you can do is verify that you only include in your `build.gradle` the dependencies you are using in your project.

You can check a similar problem in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49368827/11570855

Comment: @Shanu I have updated my answer, check it out please.

Comment: in apk analyzer, it doesnt allow write click options. So there is no way to find those folders. I was allready added minifyEnabled and shrink resources. The above picture shows my release version of apk file with apk analyzer.